# Is it possible to serialize / deserialize an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, serialization, android-arrayadapter

How would one do that and is it a good idea?

The idea is to save and restore the multiple objects stored within the adapter.

Edit: 
Basically I've got an ArrayAdapter containing multiple objects added as follows

```
adapter.add ( object );
```

I'd like to be able to save and restore the adapter so I can use it as

```
setListAdapter ( adapter );
```

I suppose it would be possible to create an ArrayList and iterate through that when I save / restore, but that seems like an extra step

Comment: Serialize the array not the array adapter

Comment: What are you trying to do? There may be a better way to do this.

Comment: What if the ArrayAdapter doesn't contain an array, but objects added as: "adapter.add ( object )"?

Comment: Please read your last comment.  I am struggling to understand how an **Array** Adapter cannot "contain" an array.

Comment: I would guess it can, but instead of adding objects to an array that I then add to the ArrayAdapter, I add the objects one and one directly to the ArrayAdapter. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Anyway, the workaround I came up with to my probem is to store all objects in an ArrayList and serialize that, instead of the ArrayAdapter as I would have liked to.